# "dvc push" after several local commits

Tags: git, dvc

I work on a project with DVC (Data version control). Let's say I make a lot of local commits. Something like this:

```
# make changes for experiment 1
dvc add my_data_file
git add my_data_file.dvc
git commit -m "Experiment 1"

# make changes for experiment 2
# which change both code and data
dvc add my_data_file
git add my_data_file.dvc
git commit -m "Experiment 2"

# make changes for experiment 3
# which change both code and data
dvc add my_data_file
git add my_data_file.dvc
git commit -m "Experiment 3"

# Finally I'm done
# push changes:
dvc push
git push
```

However there is one problem: `dvc push` will only push data from experiment 3. Is there any way to push data from all local commits (i.e. starting from the first commit diverged from remote branch)?

Currently I see two options:

1. Tag each commit and push it with `dvc push -T`
2. After "expermient 3" commit execute `git checkout commit-hash && dvc push` for all local commits not yet pushed to remote.

Both these options seem cumbersome and error-prone. Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@NShiny, there is a related ticket:

[support push/pull/metrics/gc, etc across different commits](https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/1691).

Please, give it a vote so that we know how to prioritize it.

As a workaround, I would recommend to run [`dvc install`](https://dvc.org/doc/commands-reference/install). It installs a `pre-push` GIt hook and runs `dvc push` automatically:

```
Git pre-push hook executes dvc push before git push to upload files and directories under DVC control to remote.
```

It means, though you need to run `git push` after every `git commit` :(

Comment: Thanks for your response! BTW `dvc install` documentation describes how to install DVC hooks into the repository but doesn't explain how to uninstall it. Is there a way to disable hooks after `dvc install` command?

Comment: @NShiny just remove the newly added hooks under `.git/hooks` directory

Answer (score 4):

To make it less error prone, you can use `HEAD~1` to refer to the previous commit instead of using the exact commit hash.

If you are on Bash, you can use a for loop to iterate over the last 3 commits and `dvc push` the content.

```sh
for x in {1..3}; do git checkout HEAD~1 && dvc push; done
```

Remember to `git checkout` back to your working branch (i.e. `git checkout master`)

---

Answering your comment (["dvc push" after several local commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56818930/dvc-push-after-several-local-commits/56820897#comment100200632_56820897)):

> Is there a way to disable hooks after dvc install command?

When you run `dvc install`, it creates three files under the `.git/hooks` directory:

```
.git/hooks
├── post-checkout
├── pre-commit
└── pre-push
```

To disable them, you can remove those files (i.e. `rm .git/hooks/post-checkout`).

*By the way, I edited DVC's documentation to include more information about this*.